# Adding custom panel to QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-custom-widgets

How can I add a custom panel to QGIS using Python?

For example, I want to add a panel that has a button that opens a dialogue box to choose a folder and a list in which all the tif files in the folder will be listed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is quite broad but here is a short example to get you started. It will make a [`QgsFileWidget`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/gui/File/QgsFileWidget.html) (a native widget for selecting directories/files) and place it in a dock widget on the right on the screen.

```py
def make_filewidget():
    """ generate a file widget in a container """
    
    # create the file widget
    file_widget = QgsFileWidget()
    file_widget.setObjectName('filewidget_example')
    
    # the container for the file widget that will be added to the interface
    container = QDockWidget('A file widget in a dockable container')
    container.setWidget(file_widget)
    container.setVisible(True)
    
    return container, file_widget
    
# generate the table
fw = make_filewidget()

# add the table container to the interface
iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, fw[0])
```